# Scikit Machine Learning Models - Database Storage

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there a way to store Scikit Machine Learning Models in database?

I know I can store the models in .pkl files on the disk. But I want to store it directly as a blob in my database.

```
joblib.dump(model, '../dump_file.pkl')
```

I thought of reading everything as bytes from dump_file.pkl and writing directly to the database but the problem is there are lot of supporting files generated too.
[image]

Now, how do I store my models to database??

Comment: pickle -> zip -> blob ?

Comment: Thanks! That sounds to be the potential solution. I will try.